# How to set "Task title" of a SageMaker GrountTruth labeling job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm creating a SageMaker GroundTruth Labeling Job using the console UI. I'm looking for a way to configure "Task title", which is shown in the workers Job list.

I think this is related to [TaskTitle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-create-labeling-job-api.html) configuration of AWS CLI. However, I cannot configure it from the AWS console. Can we configure it from the console GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also doing the similar stuff and running a sagemaker GT labeling job.
I am following the below git repo by amazon :

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-transformer-pipeline

If you look into the below file in the repo:

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-transformer-pipeline/blob/main/notebooks/util/smgt.py

at line no:349 ,you will see how they do it and you can do the similar change in your code.

**"TaskTitle": "Credit Card Agreement Entities"**

Hope this will help.